# Is there any way to write below code smartly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making api in the node js where in one api i call some data into one api. The problem is that this is slow, is there any way to make it more efficient?

```
constructor() {
        this.userExperienceRepository = new UserExperienceRepository();
        this.userEducationRepository = new UserEducationRepository();
        this.userCertificationRepository = new UserCertificationRepository();
        this.userExpertiseRepository = new UserExpertiseRepository();
        this.userEquipmentRepository = new UserEquipmentRepository();
        this.userRepository = new UserRepository();
    }
```

```
async findAllByUserId(id) {

    let profileDetail={};
    profileDetail.user = await this.userRepository.findAllById(id);
    profileDetail.user= deleteSecurityProperties(profileDetail.user);
    profileDetail.experience = await this.userExperienceRepository.findAllByUserId(id);
    profileDetail.education = await this.userEducationRepository.findAllByUserId(id);
    profileDetail.certification = await this.userCertificationRepository.findAllByUserId(id);
    profileDetail.expertise = await this.userExpertiseRepository.findAllByUserId(id);
    profileDetail.equipment = await this.userEquipmentRepository.findAllByUserId(id);

    return profileDetail;
    
}
```

```
}
function deleteSecurityProperties(user) {
    delete user.password;
    delete user.otp;
    delete user.otpAttempts;
    delete user.otpTimestamp;
    return user;
}
```

Comment: You could run the calls in `findAllByUserId()` in parallel. Right now you do one by one after the other which could take some time. What are these functions? Are these calls to local database OR requests to other API's ?

Comment: You seem to be assigning to `profileDetail.user` twice...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a bunch of async calls in series that don't seem to rely on one another, so you may see a slight improvement if you do them in parallel instead:

```
async findAllByUserId(id) {
    let profileDetail = {};
    profileDetail.user = await this.userRepository.findAllById(id);
    profileDetail.user = deleteSecurityProperties(profileDetail.user);
    [
        profileDetail.experience,
        profileDetail.education,
        profileDetail.certification,
        profileDetail.expertise,
        profileDetail.equipment,
    ] = await Promise.all([
        this.userExperienceRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
        this.userEducationRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
        this.userCertificationRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
        this.userExpertiseRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
        this.userEquipmentRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
    ]);

    return profileDetail;
}
```

(The array that [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) fulfills its promise with is guaranteed to be in the order of the iterable [an array in this case] it receives as input.)

You might be able to include the `profileDetail.user` assignment in there, but it wasn't clear to me what's going on there because you're assigning to it twice. Still, I *think* this does the same thing (assuming it doesn't matter when `deleteSecurityProperties` is called relative to the `findAllByUserId` calls that follow it):

```
async findAllByUserId(id) {
    let profileDetail = {};
    [
        profileDetail.user,
        profileDetail.experience,
        profileDetail.education,
        profileDetail.certification,
        profileDetail.expertise,
        profileDetail.equipment,
    ] = await Promise.all([
        this.userRepository.findAllById(id)).then(deleteSecurityProperties),
        this.userExperienceRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
        this.userEducationRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
        this.userCertificationRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
        this.userExpertiseRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
        this.userEquipmentRepository.findAllByUserId(id),
    ]);

    return profileDetail;
}
```